# Start-Locator / Locators, which is for client and which is for server?

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have been configuring Pivotal GemFire like this example:

```
@Configuration
public class GemfireConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Properties gemfireProperties() {
        Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
        gemfireProperties.setProperty("name","SpringDataGemFireApplication");
        gemfireProperties.setProperty("mcast-port", "0");
        gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", "config");
        return gemfireProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {
        CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new CacheFactoryBean();
        gemfireCache.setClose(true);
        gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties());
        return gemfireCache;
    }

    @Bean(name="employee")
    LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> getEmployee(final GemFireCache cache) {
        LocalRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> employeeRegion = new LocalRegionFactoryBean();
        employeeRegion.setCache(cache);
        employeeRegion.setName("employee");
        // ...
        return employeeRegion;
    }
}
```

I need to put a Locator "`localhost[1099]`", but when a I put:

```
gemfireProperties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[1099]");
```

I get an error from Spring saying that the Locator could not be found (more specific is `NULL`), but I change the setter with:

```
gemfireProperties.setProperty("start-locator", "localhost[1099]");
```

The app runs but I don't know if Spring creates the Locator or what happens. I want to point to `localhost[1099]` and with this way I am not sure if it is correct.

I saw many examples but it is still not clear to me which property is for client or server app.

I am working on a REST API with `spring-data-gemfire`, gemstone, etc...

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pivotal GemFire `locators` and `start-locator` properties are used by servers only.  Neither property applies to clients.

`locators` identifies the Locator(s) of the cluster that the new member will use to join as a peer.  It has the following format: `host1[port1],host2[port2],...,hostN[portN]`.

`start-locator` is used to start an embedded Locator in a peer `Cache` [application] node or server.  This property is highly convenient when starting a small cluster of GemFire servers (peer member nodes) inside your IDE.

> TIP: Typically, in standalone, production environment, you want to startup multiple, separate and dedicated Locator nodes (JVM processes, and usually on different hosts) for resiliency.  But during development, using the `start-locator` property is convenient, especially when testing.

You can read more about the `locators` and `start-locator` properties [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/reference/topics/gemfire_properties.html).  You can read more about Locators, and specifically member discovery, [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/topologies_and_comm/topology_concepts/how_member_discovery_works.html) and [here](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/topologies_and_comm/p2p_configuration/setting_up_a_p2p_system.html).

So, first question, why do you need a Locator or Locators in this instance?

Regarding...

> I need to put a Locator "localhost[1099]", but when a I put: `gemfireProperties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[1099]");` I get an error from Spring saying that the Locator could not be found (more specific is NULL), ...

This will be the case when you have not started a Locator.  If you specify `start-locator` then your Spring (Data for Pivotal GemFire), peer `Cache` application will embed a Locator (service) on startup, in which case, you do not need to specify the `locators` property since it would be redundant.

With an embedded Locator, you can then start, or have other members join this member in a cluster.

For example, I often use classes like this to start a small Pivotal GemFire cluster for development, testing and demonstration purposes...

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@CacheServerApplication(name = "ExampleServerApplication", locators = "localhost[10334]")
@PeerCacheApplication(name = "BookExampleServerApplication", locators = "localhost[10334]")
@EnablePdx(readSerialized = true)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class GeodeServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new SpringApplicationBuilder(GeodeServerApplication.class)
      .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
      .build()
      .run(args);
  }

  @Profile("locator-manager")
  @Configuration
  @EnableLocator
  @EnableManager(start = true)
  static class LocatorManagerConfiguration { }

}
```

Full source code is available [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java).

A few things to note.

First, the `@CacheServerApplication` and `@PeerCacheApplication` annotations are nearly synonymous.  They both create a Spring Boot, Pivotal GemFire peer `Cache` application node (server).  The only difference is, the `@CacheServerApplication` additionally adds a `ServerSocket` allowing GemFire `ClientCache` based applications (i.e. a Spring Boot application annotated with SDG's `@ClientClientApplication`) to connect to the server.

As you can see, I have created an inner, static `LocatorManagerConfiguration` class.  This class is annotated with `@EnableLocator` and `@EnableManager`.  `@EnableLocator` is equivalent to the `start-locator` property and allows you to control the NIC and port to which the embedded Locator service will bind to on startup.  By default, the embedded Locator service startups up on "`localhost`" bound to the default Locator port `10334`.

I added the `@EnableManager` annotation to also start the GemFire JMX-based Management service, which allows *Gfsh* to connect to our Spring Boot configured/bootstrapped GemFire server.

I enable this Spring `@Configuration` class with a Spring Profile ("`locator-manager`") so that only 1 of the servers starts with the embedded Locator/Manager.  Of course, I could have multiple servers start a Locator and/or Manager, but I then need to be careful to vary the port numbers used by the Locator and Manager services when listening for client connections (e.g. the Manager listens for connections from JMX clients like *Gfsh*, or *JConsole*, or *JVisualVM*, etc).

So, how do we run this?

Well, let's say we want to create a small GemFire cluster with 3 servers.  In my IDE, I create 3 different run profiles using the same `GeodeServerApplication` class.  The first run profile will start with the "`locator-manager`" Spring profile enabled, like so...

```
-server -ea -Dspring.profiles.active=locator-manager -Dspring.data.gemfire.name=GeodeServerOne
```

The next 2 run profiles in my IDE are setup like so...

```
-server -ea -Dspring.profiles.active=none -Dspring.data.gemfire.name=GeodeServerTwo

-server -ea -Dspring.profiles.active=none -Dspring.data.gemfire.name=GeodeServerThree
```

The only difference is, for my last run profile, run profile 3, I need to name the server something different, like "`GeodeServerThree`".  Pivotal GemFire expects the names of the peer members in the cluster to be unique.

Now, from my IDE, I can start the server with the Locator/Manager enabled first, and then run the last 2 servers without the embedded Locator/Manager enabled, next. Then, I can inspect my cluster using *Gfsh*, as follows:

```
$ echo $GEODE_HOME
/Users/jblum/pivdev/apache-geode-1.2.1

$ gfsh
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  / 
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /  
/______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    1.2.1

Monitor and Manage Apache Geode

gfsh>connect
Connecting to Locator at [host=localhost, port=10334] ..
Connecting to Manager at [host=10.0.0.121, port=1099] ..
Successfully connected to: [host=10.0.0.121, port=1099]

gfsh>list members
      Name       | Id
---------------- | ---------------------------------------------
GeodeServerOne   | 10.0.0.121(GeodeServerOne:42883)<ec><v0>:1024
GeodeServerTwo   | 10.0.0.121(GeodeServerTwo:42911)<v1>:1025
GeodeServerThree | 10.0.0.121(GeodeServerThree:42913)<v2>:1026
```

If you had enabled these Spring Boot, Pivotal GemFire peer `Cache` applications to be `CacheServers` as well (by replacing the `@PeerCacheApplication` annotation with `@CacheServerApplication`), then you would be able to connect a cache client app, similar to the following...

https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/client/BootExampleApplication.java

> TIP: The `BootExampleApplication` is using the new [*Spring Boot for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode) (SBDG) project which *auto-configures* a `ClientCache` instance, by default, when either `spring-geode-starter` or, alternatively, `spring-gemfire-starter`, is on your application's [classpath](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/pom.xml#L117-L129).  See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) for additional details.  If this project were not using SBDG, then you would explicitly have to annotate your Spring Boot application class with SDG's `@ClientCacheApplication`.

Read this [chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config) & [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-geode-applications) of the SDG Reference Guide for more details.

Anyway, I hope this gives you some guidance into what these properties are for and the power of SDG's annotations.  Also have a look at the new ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire*** project (see [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/26/spring-boot-for-apache-geode-pivotal-gemfire-1-0-0-m1-released)), which uses convention over configuration with Spring Boot's auto-configuration support to simplify configuring and bootstrapping either client or server Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire applications further.

Cheers,
-John

Comment: I understand until now that the "locators" and "start-locator" is only for servers and it could be used for testing the performance of my API, but how can I configure the URL and the credentials (user, password, etc) for connecting to a server? Beforehand, thanks for your clarification, it's so useful!