# Spring Boot Gemfire Server Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to understand how to host a Spring Boot Gemfire server process.

I found this example [Spring Gemfire Server](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example)

The problem I am having is the the server I am trying to add to the cluster is not showing up in the cluster after I start the process.

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. Start a new locator locally (default port):  `gfsh>start locator --name=loc-one`
2. I want to add this SpringBootGemfireServer to the cluster:

note I have commented out the embeded locator start-up - I want to add this to the existing locator already running

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class SpringGemFireServerApplication {

        private static final boolean DEFAULT_AUTO_STARTUP = true;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(SpringGemFireServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    private String applicationName() {
    return SpringGemFireServerApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Bean
    Properties gemfireProperties(
          @Value("${gemfire.log.level:config}") String logLevel,
          @Value("${gemfire.locator.host-port:localhost[10334]}") String locatorHostPort,
          @Value("${gemfire.manager.port:1099}") String managerPort) {

    Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();

    gemfireProperties.setProperty("name", applicationName());
    gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", logLevel);
    //gemfireProperties.setProperty("start-locator", locatorHostPort);
    //gemfireProperties.setProperty("jmx-manager", "true");
    //gemfireProperties.setProperty("jmx-manager-port", managerPort);
    //gemfireProperties.setProperty("jmx-manager-start", "true");

    return gemfireProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache(@Qualifier("gemfireProperties") Properties gemfireProperties) {

    CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache = new CacheFactoryBean();

    gemfireCache.setClose(true);
    gemfireCache.setProperties(gemfireProperties);

    return gemfireCache;
}

@Bean
CacheServerFactoryBean gemfireCacheServer(Cache gemfireCache,
        @Value("${gemfire.cache.server.bind-address:localhost}") String bindAddress,
        @Value("${gemfire.cache.server.hostname-for-clients:localhost}") String hostNameForClients,
        @Value("${gemfire.cache.server.port:40404}") int port) {

    CacheServerFactoryBean gemfireCacheServer = new CacheServerFactoryBean();


    gemfireCacheServer.setCache(gemfireCache);
    gemfireCacheServer.setAutoStartup(DEFAULT_AUTO_STARTUP);
    gemfireCacheServer.setBindAddress(bindAddress);
    gemfireCacheServer.setHostNameForClients(hostNameForClients);
    gemfireCacheServer.setPort(port);

    return gemfireCacheServer;
}

@Bean
PartitionedRegionFactoryBean<Long, Long> factorialsRegion(Cache gemfireCache,
        @Qualifier("factorialsRegionAttributes") RegionAttributes<Long, Long> factorialsRegionAttributes) {

    PartitionedRegionFactoryBean<Long, Long> factorialsRegion = new PartitionedRegionFactoryBean<>();

    factorialsRegion.setAttributes(factorialsRegionAttributes);
    factorialsRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);
    factorialsRegion.setClose(false);
    factorialsRegion.setName("Factorials");
    factorialsRegion.setPersistent(false);

    return factorialsRegion;
}

@Bean
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
RegionAttributesFactoryBean factorialsRegionAttributes() {

    RegionAttributesFactoryBean factorialsRegionAttributes = new RegionAttributesFactoryBean();

    factorialsRegionAttributes.setCacheLoader(factorialsCacheLoader());
    factorialsRegionAttributes.setKeyConstraint(Long.class);
    factorialsRegionAttributes.setValueConstraint(Long.class);

    return factorialsRegionAttributes;
}

FactorialsCacheLoader factorialsCacheLoader() {
    return new FactorialsCacheLoader();
}

class FactorialsCacheLoader implements CacheLoader<Long, Long> {

    // stupid, naive implementation of Factorial!
@Override
    public Long load(LoaderHelper<Long, Long> loaderHelper) throws CacheLoaderException {

        long number = loaderHelper.getKey();

        assert number >= 0 : String.format("Number [%d] must be greater than equal to 0", number);

        if (number <= 2L) {
            return (number < 2L ? 1L : 2L);
        }

        long result = number;

        while (number-- > 1L) {
            result *= number;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

}

When I go to `gfsh>connect list members`

I only see the locator.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the logs of your Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't verified the full configuration to check whether there's something else wrong, but the main issue I see right now is that you seem to be confusing the `start-locator` property (automatically starts a locator in the current process when the member connects to the distributed system and stops the locator when the member disconnects) with the `locators` property (the list of locators used by system members, it must be configured consistently for every member of the distributed system). Since you're not correctly setting the `locators` property when configuring the server, it just can't join the existing distributed system because it doesn't know which locator to connect to.

The default locator port used by GemFire is `10334`, so you should change your `gemfireProperties` method as follows:

```
@Bean
Properties gemfireProperties(@Value("${gemfire.log.level:config}") String logLevel, @Value("${gemfire.locator.host-port:localhost[10334]}") String locatorHostPort, @Value("${gemfire.manager.port:1099}") String managerPort) {
  Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
  gemfireProperties.setProperty("name", applicationName());
  gemfireProperties.setProperty("log-level", logLevel);
  // You can directly use the locatorHostPort variable instead.
  gemfireProperties.setProperty("locators", "localhost[10334]");

  return gemfireProperties;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Perfect.  I think I understood the start-locator process (as in it would start a new locator within the same process) - that is why I commented it out.  Since I started the locator locally (outside of the java process) and it was running on 10334 - I just assumed that the server instance would find that locator running and join that cluster.  I did not realize I still had to explicitly set the locator property.

Comment: Yes, you always have to configure the full list of locators used within the cluster in every single member.

Comment: Urizen is correct.  This is primarily because the Locator list determines the distributed system/cluster to which the new peer member will join, & therefore must be explicitly declared/set.  Previously, GemFire/Geode used mcast networking to form a cluster, but the problem with mcast is that you can end up with unexpected members in the cluster too.  So, it is better to be explicit.  A recent SO post goes into more details about the `locators` and `start-locator` properties... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659771/start-locator-locators-which-is-for-client-and-which-is-for-server

Comment: Also note, the example you cited above (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example) is a fairly old example now.  My new direction is to showcase the new Annotation-based configuration model (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config) introduced in SDG 2.0.

Comment: Here is an example server that starts a CacheServer with an embedded Locator/Manager when the `locator-manager` Spring profile is enabled (https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/server/GeodeServerApplication.java).

Comment: If you do not enable the `locator-manager` profile and rather start a Locator using Gfsh on `localhost` using the default Locator port (`10334`), then you can connect this server up to the Locator given the `@CacheServerApplication` annotation `locators` property is set to "`localhost[10334]`".  Either way, it works.  If you do not start a Locator using Gfsh, you can enable the `locator-manager` Spring profile and connect to this Spring Boot configured/bootstrapped server using `gfsh>connect`.