# Spring Data GemFire Server java.net.BindException in Linux

Tags: linux, spring-data-gemfire

I have a Spring Boot app that I am using to start a Pivotal GemFire `CacheServer`.

When I jar up the file and run it locally:

```
java -jar gemfire-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It runs fine without issue.  The server is using the default properties

```
spring.data.gemfire.cache.log-level=info
spring.data.gemfire.locators=localhost[10334]
spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.port=40404
spring.data.gemfire.name=CacheServer
spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.bind-address=localhost
spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.host-name-for-clients=localhost
```

If I deploy this to a Centos distribution and run it with the same script but passing the "test" profile:

```
java -jar gemfire-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

with my test profile `application-test.properties` looking like this:

```
spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.host-name-for-clients=server.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

I can see during startup that the server finds the Locator already running on the host (I start it through a separate process with Gfsh).

[image]

The server even joins the cluster for about a minute.  But then it shuts down because of a bind exception.

[image]

I have checked to see if there is anything running on that port (40404) - and nothing shows up

[image]

**EDIT**

Apparently I DO get this exception locally - it just takes a lot longer.

It is almost instant when I start it up on the Centos distribution.  On my Mac it takes around 2 minutes before the process throws the exception:

[image]

Adding a few more images of this:

Two bash windows - left is monitoring GF locally and right I use to check the port and start the Java process:

[image]

The server is added to the cluster.  Note the timestamp of 16:45:05.

Here is the server added and it appears to be running:

[image]

Finally, the exception after about two minutes - again look at the timestamp on the exception - 16:47:09.  The server is stopped and dropped from the cluster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you start other servers using *Gfsh*?  That is, with a Gfsh command similar to...

```
gfsh>start server --name=ExampleGfshServer --log-level=config
```

Gfsh will start `CacheServers` listening on the default `CacheServer` port of `40404`.

You have a few options.

1) First, you can disable the default `CacheServer` when starting a server with Gfsh like so...

```
gfsh>start server --name=ExampleGfshServer --log-level=config --disable-default-server
```

2) Alternatively, you can change the `CacheServer` port when starting other servers using Gfsh...

```
gfsh>start server --name=ExampleGfshServer --log-level=config --server-port=50505
```

3) If you are starting multiple instances of your Spring Boot, Pivotal GemFire `CacheServer` class, then you can vary the `spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.port` property by declaring the property as a System property when you startup.

For instance, you can, in the Spring Boot `application.properties`, do...

```
#application.properties
...
spring.data.gemfire.cache.server.port=${gemfire.cache.server.port:40404}
```

And then when starting the application from the command-line...

```
java -Dgemfire.cache.server.port=48484 -jar ...
```

Of course, you could just set the SDG property from the command line too...

```
java -Dspring.data.gemfire.cache.server.port=48484 --jar ...
```

Anyway, I guarantee you that you have another process (e.g. Pivotal GemFire `CacheServer`) with a `ServerSocket` listening on port `40404`, running.  `netstat -a | grep 40404` should give you better results.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
John

Comment: I just doubled checked.  Nothing is running on 40404 before I start the java process.  I added in a few screen shots above to show you my terminal output.  I have the locator running before I start the java process.  The java process starts and I see the server added to the cluster.  It takes about two minutes (locally) - and then the exception is thrown.

Comment: Well, most certainly something is using this port after GemFire attempts to start a `CacheServer` instance in your Spring Boot, GemFire server application.  Perhaps using `jps` on the machine where you are running the Spring Boot app will reveal what other JVM processes are running.  If you could also share your source code (as a GitHub repo) that would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Observing that you also posted this question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737079/spring-boot-gemfire-server-configuration) are you still using the `spring-boot-gemfire-server-example` app (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example) in your testing/experimenting?  Have you modified this code in anyway?  Again, please share a repo with your code/fork, whatever.